# When calling a JavaScript function, is it good practice to pass all the values as one JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, function

Should we use one JSON object and pass it to the function, or should we pass several separated parameters?

One use case would be when submitting an HTML form using JavaScript, for example.

My guess is that when you have 20 values it's easier to handle one big object than 20 different parameters. Also I guess it's easier to maintain a function when you have one parameter, but it also means that you need to validate the object properties in the function when you are using a statically typed language. Since JavaScript is not a statically typed language, I don't see the benefice of using separated parameters (we will have to manually validate each parameter in the function anyway).

What are the pros and cons of both ways, and is there a recommended way?

Thanks.

Comment: In any language, if you have more than seven parameters, you should refactor.  Too many parameters is a code smell.  See page 178 of Code Complete, 2nd edition, for more information.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Oh well... I was already writing my answer when the question was put on hold. But here it is: yes, it's okay to pass a single object as parameter: https://gist.github.com/danguilherme/ada10c3be026450a4cb24d3a85dd8ac2

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear answer I would say. Depends on what you want to achieve. For a set of an undefined amount of form fields I'd pass it as one object. Usually I pass as an object what "belongs together", for example an object of options for something.

Also, with es6 you can "cherry pick" if you only need specific parts of the object passed.

```
function({ key }) {
    return key;
}
```

is the same as

```
function(obj) {
    return obj.key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should we use one JSON object and pass it to the function, or should we pass several separated parameters?

First of all, it's not a JSON object, but a simple javascript object, [there's no such a thing "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

And to answer your question, well yes it's better to pass a param object rather than just passing all the params separately if there are several ones, even if these params can be taken as an array with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) keyword.

Some JS frameworks call it an `options` object, for example for modules it's used as an `options` object.